# How to check if image moved by finger? (Manipulation)

Tags: c#, wpf

I already working with manipulations over images on canvas. Now, I need to check, if image moved on canvas using fingers. How to do this?

```
     void Window_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {            
            Image photoToMove = e.OriginalSource as Image;
            int photoIndex = photos.IndexOf(photoToMove);            

            System.Windows.Media.Matrix rectsMatrix = ((MatrixTransform)photoToMove.RenderTransform).Matrix;
            rectsMatrix.RotateAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);
            rectsMatrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                                e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                                e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                                e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);
            rectsMatrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X,
                                  e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);
            MatrixTransform newImageMTransform = new MatrixTransform(rectsMatrix);
            photoToMove.RenderTransform = newImageMTransform;

            Rect containingRect =
                new Rect(((FrameworkElement)e.ManipulationContainer).RenderSize);

            Rect shapeBounds =
                photoToMove.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(
                    new Rect(photoToMove.RenderSize));

            if (e.IsInertial && !containingRect.Contains(shapeBounds))
            {
                e.Complete();
            }

            if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X > 0 || e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y > 0)
            {
                imageMoved = true;
            }
            else
            {
                imageMoved = false;
            }          

            e.Handled = true;

        }
```

At now, this code always says me "imageMoved == true".

Comment: You mean as opposed to being moved by mouse input?

Comment: @Clemens by mouse input all works fine (OnMouseDown/Up/Move). This app for tablet devices with touch screen. We check long press on Image and if finger pressed more then one second we show dialog (remove image?). But if user press image by finger and move for a long time we no need to show image removing dialog. Thats why we need to chek if image been moved by finger input or not

Comment: Why not simply check if the movement is above a certain threshold, e.g. `if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Length > 10) ...`

Comment: I will try it now, Clemens

Comment: @Clemens Until I moving image, this value > 0, but when I stop finger it's shows 0. So, when I stop and go on finger from screen, (value is 0) I see the qwestion for delete image, because last manipulation gives me Length = 0 :(

Comment: Then use CumulativeManipulation instead of DeltaManipulation.

Comment: I checking long press on image using difference between finger down and finger up. So, the trick is: if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Length > 10){ DateTime current1 = DateTime.Now; span1 = current1 - dt1970; };  =)
Thank you very mach, @Clemens . You can create this answer and I will apply it. :)